# Access / read adoptedStyleSheets

Tags: javascript

For a project, I would like to access all adoptedStyleSheets that got passed to a document or shadow root. I don't have any reference to stylesheet itself in this scenario.

```
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
someShadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ sheet ];
```

Is there any documented way to access or read the adoptedStyleSheets?

For more information, I'm talking about https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation even about `ShadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets`, are you using a library or some framework?

Comment: Hey @Teemu, i am talking about this: https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/ Happy to extend my question for more clarity.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(someShadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets)`?

Comment: Yeah :) it seems like adoptedStyleSheets is some strange proxy object that consumes the objects you put in. The array stays [] all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Simply printing the adoptedStyleSheets didn't work, so I did not proceed further. It turned out that iterating through the array did actually do the trick.

```
for (let i = 0; i < document.adoptedStyleSheets.length; i++) {
    console.log(document.adoptedStyleSheets[i]);
}
```

Thanks to @Justinas for pointing out the obvious.